# Couldn't create multiple tables in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, datatable

I need to create and store data in 3 tables in `SQLite` database for my first android app. I have implemented a table, where the user enters his academic details and saves it by giving it a title. In`ListActivity` the titles r displayed in a list and by clicking the list item, `ViewActivity` opens where all details under that title is displayed. This worked fine but when I created 1 more tables, the app crashed.

The `DatabaseHelper` class code is given below.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DB_NAME = "Mydata";
public static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "t1";
public static final String TITLE = "title";
public static final String NOTE = "note";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, version);
}
@Override   
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String createQuery1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME1 + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," + TITLE + ", " + NOTE + ");";
    db.execSQL(createQuery1);
    }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Database will be wipe on version change
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME1);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

The `DatabaseConnector` class code is as follows.

```
public class DatabaseConnector {
 private static final String DB_NAME = "Mydata";
 private static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "t1";
 private static final String TITLE = "title";
 private static final String ID = "_id";
 private static final String NOTE = "note";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 private SQLiteDatabase database;
 private DatabaseHelper dbOpenHelper;

public DatabaseConnector(Context context) {
    dbOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context, DB_NAME, null,
            DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void open() throws SQLException {
    database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    if (database != null)
        database.close();
}

public void InsertNote(String title, String note) {
    ContentValues newCon = new ContentValues();
    newCon.put(TITLE, title);
    newCon.put(NOTE, note);

    open();
    database.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, newCon);
    close();
}

public void UpdateNote(long id, String title, String note) {
    ContentValues editCon = new ContentValues();
    editCon.put(TITLE, title);
    editCon.put(NOTE, note);

    open();
    database.update(TABLE_NAME1, editCon, ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}

public void DeleteNote(long id) {
    open();
    database.delete(TABLE_NAME1, ID + "=" + id, null);
    close();
}

public Cursor ListAllNotes() {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME1, new String[] { ID, TITLE }, null,
            null, null, null, TITLE);
}

public Cursor GetOneNote(long id) {
    return database.query(TABLE_NAME1, null, ID + "=" + id, null, null,
            null, null);
}
}
```

There are 3 other classes to add data, to display list of titles and to display the details.
I created one more table in `DatabaseHelper` and created corresponding `DatabaseConnector` and the 3 other classes for adding & displaying details in 2nd table.

The new code of `DatabaseHelper` after adding the new table is,

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, factory, version);
}

@Override   
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    final String createQuery1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME1 + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," + TITLE + ", "   + NOTE + ");";

    final String createQuery2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME2 + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement," + TITLE1 + ", "  + NOTE1 + ");";
    db.execSQL(createQuery1);
    db.execSQL(createQuery2);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME1 + TABLE_NAME2);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

I don't even know where the problem is, whether with the table creation or with the new `DatabaseConnector` class. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You also need to define DATATYPE for `TITLE`,`NOTE`,`TITLE1`,.. columns when creating table.

Comment: Yes I did, but I didn't add it in the question. Sorry for that! Is that necessary to create one more class similar to 'DatabaseConnector' class for the second table? Because I don't even know if I'm doing it right.. :(